# react-router-redux: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...reducers

Tags: react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

[image: I'm facing this error while trying to integrate react-router-redux into my React project. Following is my app.js code and reducers/index.js]

```
//app.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { Route } from 'react-router';

import { ConnectedRouter, routerReducer, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux';

import App from './components/app.js';
import reducers from './reducers';

const history = createHistory();
const middleware = routerMiddleware(history);

// Add the reducer to your store on the `router` key
// Also apply our middleware for navigating
const store = createStore({
    ...reducers,
    router: routerReducer
  },
  applyMiddleware(middleware)
);

const About = () => {
  return (<div>
    Will this work?
  </div>);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Here is my reducers/index.js code.

```
//reducers/index.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { mobileLinks } from './reducer_header';
import UserDetailsReducer from './reducer_user_details';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  mobileLinks,
  userDetails: UserDetailsReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

What do I do to fix this? I'm unable to find any examples for the new version of react-router-redux. I've tried moving the routerReducer to reducers/index.js but that didn't work either. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you do not have Babel set to transpile the `Object Spread Operator`, you can read up on it [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/).

You can simply install the Babel "Object rest spread transform" preset like so:

`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`

And add it to your list of plugins:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        // Other plugins...
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know the solution was this simple!